# Facebook for developers, get url from photo param

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying the [API Graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), I'd like the photos param to give back the photo url but I can't set it in the GET request which currently is  graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me?fields=id,name,photos

```
"id": "22331427282551006",
  "name": "USER",
  "photos": {
    "data": [
      {
        "created_time": "2017-07-01T03:36:09+0000",
        "id": "85419012312312"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2016-06-21T04:23:13+0000",
        "id": "10112312312312311"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2016-01-31T13:03:50+0000",
        "id": "12207150957211111"
      },
      {
        "created_time": "2014-10-06T04:30:04+0000",
        "id": "12312312312312312"
```

Also tried graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me?fields=id,name,photos?type=uploaded as said in [this reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos) to get uploaded photos with unexpected errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want the content of the `images` field below the `photos` edge, so you need to ask for that explicitly as well.

```
me?fields=id,name,photos{images}
```

If you need more sub-fields of the photos edge, then you need to include those as well, comma-separated.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion